# In Access 2016 How to create a form that can record class attendance

Tags: forms, ms-access-2016

I am working in Access 2016. I need to create a form to track training attendance.  The form will have course title, date, instructor, and participants.  I want to be able to have a form that students can select their name from a dropdown when checking in and then it is added to the database.  To create a form with multiple lines for students do I create an unbound form and then link to the control source in my table that holds the roster data?